# How to send POST Request to wp rest api?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

i'm using WP REST API plugin on my wordpress website.
i want to create new post on wordpress from my android app using POST method but i dont know how to send request (headers,params).
in don't have any problem in GET method my problem is in POST and PULL method!!
how should i send JsonObjectRequest ?? 
and how should i authentication ??

```
        final JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/"+postId,
            requestJsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            onUpdateLikeComplete.onUpdate(true);
            Log.i("LikeUpdate", "onErrorResponse: "+response.toString() );
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onUpdateLikeComplete.onUpdate(false);
            Log.e("LikeUpdate", "onErrorResponse: "+error.toString() );
        }
    });
```

in this code i'm trying to update post likes

thanks for any help.